# How to use formula to calculate sum of sequence in R?

Tags: r

I'm wonder is there already some forumla function ready to ues, for example?

```
sum(seq(10)) = 55
```

It could use math formula by n to calculate for faster response.  But I don't know what's the proper keyword to found out is there builtin formula or already exist in R reposotory?

Comment: And what's wrong with `sum(seq(10))`?

Comment: `n(n+1)/2=10*11/2=55`

Comment: Yes, I know the formula, but I'm wonder is there built-in or already exist package which contains these formula on text books.